# Android contact content provider using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I'm taking a course in Android development and thus i'm fairly new to this whole thing. I need to make get a contact through an intent, get the id and name of the contact and display it in a ListView. 
I have tried to follow instructions from my course but I just can't get it to work. it crashes when i hit the "invite someone" button.


here is the Actiivty:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Invite someone"
        android:onClick="pickContact"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="contact here" />
```

and this is the code in the corresponding java file:

```
public class Event extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView myContactTextView;
private static int PICK_CONTACT_REQ = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_event);

    myContactTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactTextView);
}


public void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQ);

    onActivityResult();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQ) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // The user picked a contact.
            // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            try {
                myContactTextView.setText("Your device has these contacts");

                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int id = cursor.getInt(idColumn);
                        String contactName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);

                        myContactTextView.append(("\n" + id + "-" + contactName));
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

can someone help?

edit: I get this meassage in the Android Monitor:

```
05-30 11:05:30.539 18746-18746/com.company.reds.awesomeapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.company.reds.awesomeapp, PID: 18746
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method pickContact(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
                                                                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: define: *it crashes* (like a programmer not a user)

Comment: not sure if what you are looking for, but I added the message from the Android monitor in the original post. The app closes down, and the old "unfortunately "app" has stopped" message pops up.

Comment: I was thinking about logcat's log ... Exception is self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.
I forgot to add View view to my intent

edit: mentioned below I added View view to the the pickContact() method not the intent.

Comment: *I forgot to add View view to my intent* ... rather `View view` as parameter in `pickContact` method

Comment: Yes your right. I made an edit to my answer. I still have a problem, but I don't know if it is good practice to open a new question for that?

Comment: First of all read the new exception... **then try to google for it** ... if you would not find similar question (and exception/problem is different than in this question) then ask another